Can i pray so Allah will make a girl I loved and now died mine in janna?
I have I girl that I love and she's always trying to bring me closer to Allah and now she's no more, so I will like to be with her in jannah so I want to know if Allah can grant my wishes

These are really a lot of questions, not only one. You say "she's no more". So she died? Now what if she is in jannah but has different plans? What if she's not in jannah? These are many possibilities and so the question splits up. I would like to see an answer for every aspect, based on Islam. I have seen more than one married people where husband or wife have died, waiting to meet them again in heaven. It is not a good state of mind giving up hope and life for death to come. Live your life that Allah has given you.
